# Why did ERC165 adopt XOR?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, erc165

Why did ERC165 adopt XOR among the many bitwise operators?

Comment: could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using the XOR operator in particular is that it allows the interface identifier to be checked in a simple and efficient manner, without the need for a loop or other complex control flow.